# How can I make my routers DHCP server issue a IP so my QEmu VM can be accessed anywhere from the network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, qemu, cisco

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine running Docker and LXD. Therfore it has a Docker0 bridge and a LXDBR0 bridge.

I need to connect a QEMU VM (vManage) to my local network so I can access it from any machine. What suggestions are there to make my VM accesible from outside it's container?

I could forward the ports but unfortunately there are so many of them it would be best to just give it a virtual VEth that can get Router issued IP's and not DNSMasq form LXD, Docker
or a Bridged DHCP ones.